# Map nested models in asp.net core views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create roles with respective claims in asp.net core 2+, so I create a view like:

```
@page
@model Security.Dto.Models.ApplicationRoleModel

<form asp-controller="security" asp-action="CreateRole" method="post">

    <h4>Create new Role</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group" id="item-list">
        <label>Role Name</label>
        <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].Role.Name" class="form-control roles" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add">Add another</a>


    <div class="form-group" id="claim-list">
        <label>Claim Type</label>
        <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].ClaimList[0].Type" class="form-control " />
        <label>Claim Value</label>
        <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].ClaimList[0].Value" class="form-control claims" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>

</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#add").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var i = ($(".roles").length);
                var n = '<label>Role Name</label><input class="form-control roles" name="RoleClaimList[' + i + '].Role.Name" />'
                $("#item-list").append(n);
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(ApplicationRoleModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in model.RoleClaimList)
                {
                    var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item.Role.Name);
                    if (roleExists) continue;
                    var createRole = _roleManager.CreateAsync(item.Role);
                    foreach (var claim in item.ClaimList)
                    {
                        await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(item.Role, claim);
                    }
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

ApplicationRoleModel:

```
public class ApplicationRoleModel 
    {
        public List<RoleClaimModel> RoleClaimList { get; set; }
      
    }
```

RoleClaimModel:

```
 public class ClaimsToRoleModel
    {
        public List<RoleClaimModel> RoleClaimList { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleClaimModel
    {
        public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
        public List<Claim> ClaimList { get; set; }
    }
```

So when I run and debbug it, `Role` come correctly but `ClaimList` always count 0 or come null

[image]

Someone looks what am I doing wrong? How can I map `ClaimList` property model correctly from view?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused because the `Claim` class doesn't have a [constructor that takes 0 parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim.-ctor?view=netcore-2.1) so when the framework attempts to create a new one it cannot, so you end up with an empty or null object.

To solve the issue you need to use your own custom class in your hierarchy:

```
public class CustomClaim
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RoleClaimModel
{
    public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public List<CustomClaim> ClaimList { get; set; }
}
```

Now the framework can create the `CustomClaim` and serialize it to your API. In your controller you can translate your `CustomClaim` into the .NET `Claim` and pass that to your `_roleManager`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(ApplicationRoleModel model)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in model.RoleClaimList)
        {
            var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item.Role.Name);
            if (roleExists) continue;
            var createRole = _roleManager.CreateAsync(item.Role);
            foreach (var claim in item.ClaimList)
            {
                var c = new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value);

                await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(item.Role, c);
            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```